# Should I generally rely on pointers or First class functions in Go/Golang?

Tags: go

Let's say I wanted to write a function `sum` that sums 2 integers and prints the result. This would be my first instinct:

```golang
func main() {
 println(sum(2,3))
}

func sum(x int, y int) int{
 return x + y
}
```

However, from the Go code I've been seeing a lot of people favor use of pointers, something closer to this:

```golang
func main() {

 x:= 2;
 y:= 3; 
    
 println(add(&x, &y))
}

func sum( x *int, y *int) int {
    return *x + *y
}
```

Can someone shine light on any benefits, whether it be performance or readability about one or the other or if I'm attempting to be a pedant and this is arbitrary?

Comment: If a function can modify its arguments, those arguments should be passed as pointers. If it only uses those arguments to compute something, they should be passed as value. In your case, there is no reason to pass them as pointers. Don't trust every piece of code you see online.